# Avalonia How To Create Custom Popup

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

A little explanation first:

This is source code of [Popup element](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/Primitives/Popup.cs)

And this is example of using Popup [DatePicker](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/DateTimePickers/DatePicker.cs) and [it's xaml](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Default/DatePicker.xaml)

I've tried use this example on empty window like this

[image: Sample Code]

Here is result:

[image]

So I want to create a OK/Cancel pick panel and use like DateTimePicker Pop and Select what do you want and accept or abort the selections.

How can I create a simple custom picker like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Here is My [DateTimePicker](https://tr1.in/oRwSASA) and screenshots
[image]

After Tap

[image]

Ok I analyzed the existing codes for hours. Simply the answer is:

Step 1: Create a presenter class for manage your controls and events for popup. (like [DatePickerPresenter](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Controls/DateTimePickers/DatePickerPresenter.cs)

```
namespace AvaloniaTest.Views {
  public class SabriPresenter : PickerPresenterBase
  {
  ...

  }
}
```

Step 2: Create Template for this presenter in your window or resource.

```
<Window xmlns="bla bla bla"
        xmlns:v="using:AvaloniaTest.Views"
        Title="AvaloniaTest">

  <Design.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
  </Design.DataContext>

  <Window.Styles>
    <Style Selector="v|SabriPresenter" >
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Panel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
              <TextBlock Text="Your content..."/>
            </Panel>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="OK"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Cancel"/>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Styles>
</Window>
```

Step 3: Use this presenter wherever you want

```
<Window xmlns="bla bla"
        xmlns:v="using:AvaloniaTest.Views"
        >
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Greeting}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Content="Popeye"  Name="sabri"/>
    <Popup Name="Popup"
           WindowManagerAddShadowHint="False"
           StaysOpen="False"
           PlacementMode="Bottom"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=sabri}"
           >
      <v:SabriPresenter />
    </Popup>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Ta-daa!
[image]